# Parse Wordpress JSON into UITableView on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, wordpress

I'm trying to parse a JSON from [this URL](http://www.karthikk.net/?json=1), which is a JSON output from Wordpress. For some reason, there's no output in the UITableView.

Here's the code I have got to parse. I'm sure I'm missing out something but I'm not able to figure out how to parse Nested JSON in this code.

**ViewController.m:**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"News";

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.karthikk.net/?json=1"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - please make sure you're connected to either 3G or Wi-Fi." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [news count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];

    return cell;
}
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;

    NSArray *news;
    NSMutableData *data;
}

@end
```

Please help me out in paring this.

Thanks much! I've tried referring to multiple threads on Stackoverflow, but all failed to work for me.

**P.S.:** I'm a newbie to iOS App Development. And I'm using [this Video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJZcD3hfs3k) to mess with the code.

Comment: What if any errors are you getting?  Without knowing what your header file looks like it's difficult to just copy/paste your code and see what's happening.

Comment: Do this: NSLog(@"news = %@", [news description]); right after you assign news to the JSON value  And post the result (if the result is huge, post the first few objects)

Comment: I've updated the question with the header file. And @ElJay, How can I do that? Could you please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see what the problem is.  The news object is a `Dictionary` that has several key value pairs and one of them is posts which actually contains the `Array` that you want to use to populate your `TableView`.

Here is the first little bit from your `JSON` response:

```
{"status":"ok","count":10,"count_total":662,"pages":67,"posts":[{"id":6176,"type":"post","slug":"how-to-save-any-photo-from-facebook-to-your-iphone-or-ipad-or-ipod-touch","url"...
```

When you see a { in a `JSON` response that indicates a `Dictionary`, a [ indicates an `Array`.  `TableViews` are populated from an `Array` usually.  So you can see that you have a `JSON` response of a `Dictionary` with several key-value pairs and one of those is an `Array` of `Dictionary`'s

You need to assign the news object the contents of that Dictionary key:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    news = [responseDict objectForKey@"posts"];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. It worked just as I wanted it to work! Thanks much! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anytime, this was a good question and the code you posted (along with that link) helped figure out the problem pretty quickly :)

Comment: Thanks again. Now figuring out to display images which are in the posts.

Comment: Look at my answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786018/loading-an-image-into-uiimage-asynchronously  I wrote a class just for this.

Comment: Another quick query: How do I access the inner array in the JSON. Like the thumbnail and author name? Could you please help me with that? @ElJay

Comment: The images object (dictionary) is actually what you need and the thumbnail object inside of that is another dictionary , you would just need to use something like NSDictionary *imagesDict = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"images"]; to create a dictionary and then something like: NSDictionary *thumbailDict = [images objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];  Then it is just a matter of doing : NSString *urlString = [thumbnailDict valueForKey@"url"];  To get author will be much of the same thing.