# how can I display UIImage from image url

Tags: iphone, ios

The code below works fine if I give statically but

```
imgDescView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://4cing.com/mobile_app/uploads/pageicon/6.jpg"]]]];
```

Same code - I am passing the image url name dynamically it's not working

```
imgDescView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imagename objectAtIndex:0]]]];
```

Comment: print [imagename objectAtIndex:0] and check its equal to http://4cing.com/mobile_app/uploads/pageicon/6.jpg

Comment: have you  logged the [imagename objectAtIndex:0]? then what is result ?

Comment: 1 Closing Bracket Missing at end..
imgDescView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:  
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imagename objectAtIndex:0]]]]];

Comment: can you paste [imagename objectAtIndex:0] ??

Comment: 2013-03-20 14:44:40.697 SMSCollection[442:1a303] 4cing.com/mobile_app/uploads/pageicon/6.jpg

Comment: URL is not created. So u need to add http:// before [imagename objectAtIndex:0] and it should work!!!

Comment: @RayofHope how would it compile if Closing Bracket was Missing at end.

Comment: @RayofHope: +1 for observation.. Thumbs up..:)

Comment: Check the array whether it is storing images or not..bcoz what i see u r unable to access it from array..

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *imagename = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"http://4cing.com/mobile_app/uploads/pageicon/6.jpg", nil];
UIImageView *imgDescView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 200)];

imgDescView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                            [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imagename objectAtIndex:0]]]]];
```

it is working ... i think u r not creating array properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify the `NSArray` contents.  Log out the objects of the array:

```
NSLog(@"imagename = %@",[imagename description]);
```

Also, a side-note - might want to think about loading that image dynamically.  I wrote a class that makes this pretty painless:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9786513/585320

The answer is geared toward using in `TableViews` (where lag would really hurt performance), but you can (and I do) use this for any web image loading.  This keeps the UI fluid and is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Hi create url in this manner

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imagename objectAtIndex:0]] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
```

i think it will work and will resolve ur problem.