# Store Image to iPhone with lag

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS app that needs to download an image to display it the next time if the app has no internet connection.

I get the URL to download this image from a request to a server, I get a json back with a field "image" with the url of the image. To download and store this image I do the following:

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:utfString]];
[data writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectoryPath,@"superPremio"] atomically:NO];
```

This is called inside a successfully server call block. So I'm not doing this synchronously. This server call is being made in the `viewDidLoad` of the view controller that needs to display the image. This view controller has a UIScrollView and this scroll view is experimenting a lag when the image is written to the memory. Everything is done in background processing so I'm not sure why this is happening... any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data fetching process

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:utfString]];
```

is not asynchronous and it is causing trouble  of lagging the 
UI

Use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9786513/1704346) for making it asynchronous