# UITableview with images scroll very slowly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have an `UITableView` which downloads its `UITableViewCell`s images from a server.

I observed that the table scrolls very slowly.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"parallaxCell";
    JBParallaxCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Resim"]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];


    cell.titleLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Adi"];
    cell.subtitleLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Resim"];
    cell.parallaxImage.image = imageLoad;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage to load your images lazily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this Library which is just perfect

- [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

You just need to `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` to your project, and you can define also the placeholder when image is being downloaded with just this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell;
}
```

It also cache downloaded images and gives you great performance.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: I am glad it helps you! You can vote up this answer and setting it the correct answer by checking the tick! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are loading image file on main thread and this operation is slowing your scroll. Use `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` from AFNetworking to speed up your app by async image loading. link https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

Load the images asynchronously. It will help you :

[Loading an image into UIImage asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786018/loading-an-image-into-uiimage-asynchronously)

[Link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)