# Activity indicator for button

Tags: ios, objective-c, gridview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a grid view with images downloaded from internet . When i clicked to one button to get in that view it's take time and the first screen is frozen ,the second view is displayed only when all the images are downloaded. How can i put an activity indicator on the time in which I have to waiting ?

Comment: try to use the NSURLConnection delegate methods and add UIActivityIndicatorView as subview

Comment: you should download image asynchronously. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786018/loading-an-image-into-uiimage-asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Add the activity view to your cell/view like so:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
```

Call `[spinner stopAnimating];` and remove it from it's superView when the NSURLConnection delegate methods inform you they are finished.

Also ensure you only call the above code (which interacts with the UI) on the main thread.

Comment: When i press my button, the screen is frozen , here is my problem . The next view is displayed only when the all images are downloaded.

Comment: How are you fetching the images? It sounds like you are blocking the main thread which is why the UI freezes. You need to perform the image fetch on a background thread (using Grand Central Dispatch with NSURLConnection or (better) a background NSURLSession). Then you will be able to show a UIActivityIndicatorView to highlight to the user that work is being done in the background while they wait for the images to download. I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to put activity indicator and wait to statically download all images .. just imagine if there is 1000 pictures and the user must wait till download is done to became start using your application.

> I'll assume this gridView is tableView because in mobile design world
>   gridView doesn't exits.

**View Did Load**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg", @"http://1hdwallpapers.com/wallpapers/creativity_water_spray_drops_flower_rose_desktop_images.jpg" , @"http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02848/wellcome-photo-13__2848386k.jpg" ,@"http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" , @"http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/images/Frozen-Logo-Symbol-HD-Images.jpg" , @"http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg" , @"http://www.desktopwallpaperhd.net/wallpapers/21/7/wallpaper-sunset-images-back-217159.jpg" ,    nil];

    tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 20) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

// DO NOT FORGET UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource protocols
    [tableView setDelegate:self];
    [tableView setDataSource:self];

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

> Rows count:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [array count];
}
```

> Cell configuration

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//You need a global declaration for cell

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellID"];

        [self getImagesAsyncFor:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

> Now getImagesAsync method

```
-(void)getImagesAsyncFor:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath_ {

    // Fetch using GCD
    dispatch_queue_t downloadThumbnailQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Get Photo Thumbnail", NULL);

    dispatch_async(downloadThumbnailQueue, ^{

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath_.row]]]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell = [self->tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath_]; // create a copy of the cell to avoid keeping a strong pointer to "cell" since that one may have been reused by the time the block is ready to update it.
            if (cell != nil) {

                [cell.imageView setImage:image];
                [cell setNeedsLayout];

            }
        });
    });

}
```

Now when you open the application you should see how images download one after one async and you still can interact with the application.
After the download is finish the UI of your tableView will be updated automatically with this method:
                [cell setNeedsLayout];

This is the way all modern applications are build it like, facebook, twitter, google+ etc.

Comment: i'm using a collection view

Comment: Well i'am sure that this code will help you with the collection view too .. i just never have worked yet with collection view to make an example, sorry for my miss understanding, All best.